# Windows 7 boots instead of Ubuntu 12.04 while the Ubuntu CD is inside device

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, dvd

I am trying dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7.

I downloaded the ISO from the site and burned it on a DVD.
Now when I run wubi.exe (as auto play) it says "Permission Denied". After googling it, I found that it is just a bug and that it is properly installed already.

Now I am trying to boot the laptop while the disc inside, but it unconditionally boots Windows 7.

How do I get the option to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you set your BIOS to boot from the CD?

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate on the previous answer, you need to:

1: When your PC is booting, press the relevant "F key" to get you into your BIOS.

2: Navigate to the menu entitled "Boot"

3: Configure the settings in that menu to boot from the CD first.

4: Exit and Save Changes.

5: Your computer should reboot automatically, and boot from the CD.